# Unable to deserialize the kml

Tags: c#, xml, kml

I have the following Kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Trains</name>
    <description/>
      <name>Red Train</name>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

and the following code to deserialize it

```
private void KmlToObject()
{
    var path = @"C:\Users\Downloads\test.kml";
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Kml));
    using var reader = new StringReader(path);
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Kml;
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "kml")]
public class Kml
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Document")]
    public object Document { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`StringReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0) is not the way to read the file.

> Initializes a new instance of the StringReader class that reads from the specified string.

Instead, you should look for `StreamReader` with the [ReadToEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-7.0) method. Reference: [How to: Read text from a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file)

```cs
var path = @"C:\Users\Downloads\test.kml";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Kml));

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(sr.ReadToEnd()) as Kml;
}
```

And provide the `Namespace` to `XmlRoot` attribute.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "kml", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2")]
public class Kml
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input file is not valid KML.  A Document tag can only contain one name tag, and it looks like yours contains a name, an empty description, and then another name tag.  Maybe you intended for the Document to contain a Placemark tag and have that contain the name "Red Train"?